# Can I emulate a wi-fi connection to test Wi-fi Direct?

Tags: android, android-wifi

In API 14 or higher (ICS), ad-hoc wi-fi networks are possible. I currently possess the following, and I'm trying to figure out how I might test the wi-fi direct functionality, or if I need to get another device with Android 4.0.

- Computer, connected via a wired network to a wi-fi router.
- A Galaxy Nexus, fully update.

Comment: My solution so far is to by an Amazon Kindle, but I'm still curious how I could do this with an emulator/handheld...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that from a User Experience prospective, Wi-Fi Direct functionality in Android is quite crappy. Yes, it does have an API for negotiating and controlling Wi-Fi Direct connections, but "vanilla" Android doesn't have any user applications for negotiation this connection if user need it.

If yo are software developer and developing multi player game Android game, you have everything you need:

- API to enable Wi-Fi Direct
- to receive list of all devices nearby with enabled Wi-Fi Direct
- to send connect request to another device
- to accept this request and establish connection

But if you are just a user who has two devices and multi player games which can't negotiate about establishing Wi-Fi Direct connection, and and just want to connect two devices without Access Point, we are sorry.

So, if you just want to test Wi-Fi Direct functionality on your device, there are two ways to do this:

- Buy / borrow device which has appropriate software "from the box", like [Sony Xperia T](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xr9kva_sony-xperia-s-connectivity-dlna-wifi-direct-hdmi_tech), [Samsung Galaxy SII](http://youtu.be/1z-vMD4JuWc?hd=1) or [Samsung Galaxy SIII](http://youtu.be/ENteq-canMk?hd=1).
- Install third party application from Android Market, like [WiFi Shoot!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.budius.WiFiShoot), [WiFi Direct](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.wifidirect), etc.

Hope I answered your question.